# Semigroup algebra of an idempotent semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, algebras, group-rings

Let us consider $S=\{1,2\}$ with the operation $xy=\max\{x,y\}$. Then $S$ is a commutative semigroup with unity. Consider its complex algebra $\mathbb C[S]={\rm span}\{e_1, e_2\}$, where $e_i e_j = e_{ij}$. This algebra is unital as $e_1$ is the unit. Then $e_1, e_2$ and $e_1 - e_2$ are idempotents in this algebra so it cannot be isomorphic to the algebra of upper-triangular matirces with constant diagonal. However, [there are only 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704068/two-dimensional-unital-complex-banach-algebras) (up to isomorphism) complex unital algebras. $\mathbb C[S]$ so it must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}\oplus \mathbb{C}$, right?

Comment: With the notation of the cited SE page,  now we have $x^2=x$ and case 2. applies with 2 idempotents, now namely $e=e_1$ and $x=e_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like

$$
\begin{align*}
e_1 &\leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \\
e_2 &\leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
$$